# Runner got struck after running the test cases I am using 1.1.0 version

Tags: karate

I d/w the code via  maven as instructed and able to run successfully for few instances. later when I ran the same scenario ( which was working earlier) , got 200 Ok response for one service request and then log got struck. I have to manually terminate the run ( using CTRL + C).
above one I tried with parallel run.
Later I tried to run the same scenario with running only one feature. while running that, got below error.

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3

I tried to run the code with external download JAR option as well. getting same error.

Comment: please follow this process, there is no other way to solve this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: By reading the other answer similar to my query, I understood there is an error in my feature file. I will try to look into closely whats the issue.

Comment: identified that I didnt used "" in examples which return in JSON error ( but did not get that error during parallel). Later I ran using single runner class, its working. But when I ran with parallel option, still it got hanged.

Comment: I have nothing to add to my comment above.